# how to download iOS 10.3.3 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, download, ios-simulator, simulator

I wanted to try my app on `iPhone 6` with `iOS 10.3.3` but I couldn't find `iOS 10.3.3` in simulators

[image]

any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't download it from this window, as Apple does not release/provides simulator for each version/subversions of iOS.

Here I've simulator list with Xcode 9.3, Component window. It seems apple has not provided simulator for 10.3.3.

[image]

---

You can also add/find a simulator from Xcode Target:

1. Open simulator list against your Xcode target and **Add Additional Simulators...**

   [image]
2. Switch to **Simulators** and click on **+**

   [image]
3. Select **Device Type**, **iOS Version** and **Create** simulator.

   [image]

Comment: Just a query. I don't think create a new simulator option is no longer available.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh I think you're on Xcode beta, that's why you don't see a download option, no?